# Vaadin leaflet combining markers

Tags: leaflet, vaadin

I have a [V-Leaflet](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet) map. 
Depending on what the backend "says" (where/how-many), there'll be marker(s) on this map. 
When 2 or more of these markers are closely located and thus overlap, 
i'll look to combine them into one marker that refers to them all.

The only way i can think of is the explicit way -- getting the `Bounds` (`org.vaadin.addon.leaflet.shared.Bounds`) 
of the portion of the map in view and going from there 
(calculate how close/apart now those markers are, group/ungroup them accordingly.)

Is there a built-in/quicker way of doing this?

**Note:** i'm not interested in the mathematical/clustering part of the problem. 
checking just not to miss out -- dont wanna redo if this is coded.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [V-Leaflet Markercluster extension](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/v-leaflet-markercluster-extensions):

> Server side api for Leaflet Markercluster extension

It wraps [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin:

> Provides Beautiful Animated Marker Clustering functionality for Leaflet, a JS library for interactive maps.

Comment: is there an example showing how to use it in the backend/Java code? i'm not js-savy and couldnt find anthing.

Comment: See the [demo and test app](https://github.com/willtemperley/v-leaflet-markercluster-parent/tree/master/v-leaflet-markercluster/src/test/java/org/vaadin/addon/leaflet/demoandtestapp).